# Error ngerman.sty not found using texmaker on windows 10

Tags: texmaker, windows

This is the error: 
! LaTeX Error: File `ngerman.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Please help! :-/
Thank you

Comment: do not use `\usepackage[ngerman}`. Use instead `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. However, give a complete example.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `german` and `ngerman` packages are largely obsolete; avoid them and do as Herbert recommends; don't forget to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and, possibly, `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Unfortunately none of it worked... I now downloaded ngerman.sty again but that didnt help either.
As to the MWE, i dont know how to do that as i am using a template from Uni... :-/